# CSS: propery syntax to refer to element with ID

Tags: css

Ref this tutorial: https://www.servage.net/blog/2009/03/20/create-a-cool-css-based-drop-down-menu/

I used an external stylesheet, and simply put #menu before each CSS item, like this:

```
#menu ul{
font-family: Arial, Verdana;
font-size: 14px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;}
```

or:

```
#menu ul li{
display: block;
position: relative;
float: left;}
```

But, when i reference with #menu, the menu doesn't render properly. It leaves the parent 'li' untouched by CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/UGW2L/

Any ideas?

Thx,
Dave

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle example? Also, you can try my tutorial http://www.onextrapixel.com/2011/06/03/how-to-create-a-horizontal-dropdown-menu-with-html-css-and-jquery/

Comment: Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/UGW2L/

Comment: it works fine on Chrome, I saw a drop down menu

Comment: You've edited the question totally rendering all previous answers meaningless.  To preserve the integrity of this thread, I'm rolling it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#menu ul` targets this (any `ul` **inside** of an element with `id='menu'`)...

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul> <!-- <<-- this element is the target -->
       ...
    </ul>
</div>
```

(`div` is just an example, any element with `id="menu"` can be used above)

---

`ul#menu` targets this (the `ul` **with** `id='menu'`)...

```
<ul id="menu">  <!-- <<-- this element is the target -->
    ...
</ul>
```

---

**Edit as per comments:**

Quote:  *"...i am missing the 'box' around the parent node."*

I think the node to which you refer is the `<li>`, just inside the parent `<ul id='menu'>`, and you have not targeted it anyplace at all.

Just add `ul#menu li a` to your box styling.  (Note the comma.  It separates two totally unique selectors sharing the same styling.)

```
ul#menu li a,
ul#menu ul li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  background: #2C5463;
  margin-left: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cWpEg/1/

See the difference?

`ul#menu` is the parent.
`ul#menu li` is the first item inside the parent.
`ul#menu li a` is the link inside the first child of the parent.

Since `ul#menu li` targets **any & all** `<li>`'s that are children of the `ul#menu` parent, you would only need the one selector...

```
ul#menu li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-top: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  background: #2C5463;
  margin-left: 1px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cWpEg/2/

Also note how it's the full width of the screen.

To target & style just the parent, add something like this.

```
ul#menu {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  list-style: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cWpEg/6/

Comment: If you see the live example here, i am missing the 'box' around the parent node: https://www.servage.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/css-menu.html

Comment: @user1163859: It does work.  You are still failing to target the parent element directly.  See my edits.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the 'edit'. I'm new. Appriciate the detailed answer. Works perfect!

Comment: @user1163859: Add `list-style: none;` to `ul#menu`.  See my edited answer and this:  http://jsfiddle.net/cWpEg/6/

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML is this:

```
<ul id="menu">
```

Which means your CSS needs to be this:

```
ul#menu
```

Your current CSS is looking for an 'LI inside of a UL that is inside of some other element with an ID of MENU'

Comment: I'm using an external stylesheet, and i can't get this to work properly. The child-li is still visible. I'v done everything from scratch many times, and its always the same. It works when i incorporate CSS into the html page, but not when loaded externally. Am i missing something here?

Comment: It means your link to your external CSS file is likely incorrect.

Comment: No, because most of the CSS is rendering fine....its just the 'li which is not. Hmmmm....i'll upload a pic for you to see

Comment: As you can see...there is a list dot to the left of the button....this doesn't go away unless i put the CSS in the html page